# wrong number of arguments (3 for 2) in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

in my  rails app I have millions of records and i need to use pagination by mysql but I am getting this error "wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)" . 
my sql syntax

```
 @tweets=Tweets.paginate_by_sql(sql, :@page, :per_page => @per_page ).all
```

Anybody kindly help me with this. thks in advance , stuck wid dis from a long tym

```
class CoordinatesController < ApplicationController
  def home 
  end
  def paramas(b)

    @b = params[:show]
    return @b

  end
  def coor(latitude,longitude)
    @latitude=0
    @longitude=0
  end

  def query
    @a=Coordinates.where("city= ?",params[:show]) 
    if(params[:show]== a.city) then 
      @latitude= a.latitude
      @longitude=a.longitude
    end
    if(@latitude=0 && @longitude=0) then
      return  @sql="Select * from tweets where tweet_text LIKE '%text%' AND user_loc LIKE 'paramas' order by id desc"
    else if (@latitude!=0 && @longitude!=0) 
           @min_lat = @latitude - 1.0
           @max_lat = @latitude + 1.0
           @min_lng = @longitude - 1.0
           @max_lng = @longitude + 1.0
           return   @sql = "Select * from tweets where tweet_text LIKE '%text%' AND ( ((longitude BETWEEN min_lng and max_lng) AND (latitude BETWEEN min_lat and max_lat)) OR (user_loc LIKE 'paramas') ) order by id desc"
         else
           return   @sql="Select * from  tweets where tweet_text LIKE  '%text%'"
         end    

    end
```

my code for tweets_controller

```
class TweetsController < ApplicationController

include CoordinatesHelper
  def search
    render 'tweets/search'
  end


  def index

   # include CoordinatesHelper
    sql=query
    @tweets=Tweets.paginate_by_sql(sql, :@page, :per_page => @per_page ).all
    #render 'tweets/index'
  end
end
```

@tweets=Tweets.paginate_by_sql(sql, :@page, :per_page => @per_page ).all. I am getting error in this line
anybody help me wat s d error . thks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paginate_by_sql` accepts 2 arguments - the SQL query and the options hash. If you want to use SQL sanitation, you need to send the SQL query template and the params in a single array, like so:

```
@tweets=Tweets.paginate_by_sql([sql, @page], :per_page => @per_page ).all
```

**Edit**:

My Bad - I thought that @page was a parameter for the SQL sanitizer.

Anyways, you need to send the page via the options has:

```
@tweets=Tweets.paginate_by_sql(sql, :page => @page, :per_page => @per_page ).all
```

Comment: thk u very much dis brought me very close but where  should i specify the  number of records per page. pls help

Comment: wherever i specify it says , @ followed by no of records it says  its not allowed as an instance variable